# Unable to write Compressed messages to Kafka topic from Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We are using Spark Structured Streaming (3.2.1) to write into Kafka(0.10) topic. Since data volume is high, we are trying to write the data in Compressed format (snappy). But we do not see any effect on this. Also spark complains about 'compression.type' property is unknown. Does Spark Structured streaming support writing compressed messages to Kafka topic? If yes, what should be the configuration?
Sample Code:

```scala
var dataStreamWriter = 
       finalDf
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("topic", topic)
      .option("kafka.compression.type", "snappy")
      .option("kafka.batch.size", "1024000")
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(triggerDuration + " seconds"))
```

Comment: Show code pls. Need kafka. as pregix

Comment: sample code added...